# Add line to plot for Zipf's law

Tags: r

I am quite a rookie using R. I have acquired a huge amount of data from my research. Now I wish to make a plot that shows whether or not the data is following Zipf's law.

This is the command I use so far:

```
plot(data, log="y", type="l", main="Zipf",ylab="frequency", xlab="tag index")
```

It already gives me a nice plot however, now I wish to add a straight line to indicate what part of the plot is following the Zipf's law. I have tried several commands but nothing worked out, can someone please explain how I can get this to work?

Comment: As you don't provide any of the commands you already tried, we don't know whether you already tried a command such as `abline`.

Comment: I have used `abline(a = coef(data), b = 0, col = "blue")` but it gives me an error since I have not the knowledge how to use the commands properly.

Comment: We don't know what `data` is. What `abline(coef=coef(data), col='blue')` gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the line with command abline. If you need to add horizantal line, use argument 'h'
and for vertical line use 'v'. For example if you have to add a vertical line at x-axis value = 5, the code is:

```
plot(data, log="y", type="l", main="Zipf",ylab="frequency", xlab="tag index")
abline(v = 5)
```

If you want to add a slant line, then obtain the equation of line in the form of **y = mx + c**. In this 'm' is called slope and 'c' is called intercept. so your code would be.

```
plot(data, log="y", type="l", main="Zipf",ylab="frequency", xlab="tag index")
    abline(a=c,b=m)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i will mess around with this slant line and i'll get back to you when i run into a problem OR when it solves my problem.

Comment: when for example I type in `abline(a=-1,b=1)` I get no errors but it does not show any line ??

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 if it is not in the ranges of your plot, it is normal.

Comment: x<-rnorm(10)
 y<-rnorm(10)
 plot(x,y)
 abline(-1,1) This code is working for me.